# In a MFC application, how to use two timers?

Tags: c++, mfc

In a MFC application, how to use more than one timers, and in Ontimer function how to recognize the diferrent timer and to execute the differrent code.

Comment: I am not sure what you are getting at, the `OnTimer (...)` event handler clearly has a parameter that indicates which timer generated the event. See the MSDN documentation for `CWnd::OnTimer (...)`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fy1hkbdk%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: I am so stupid, can you show me some code, I need two timer ,thanks very much...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CWnd::SetTimer returns a timer identifier. For each timer you create you should store its id number.

When the CWnd::OnTimer is called, it receives one parameter that corresponds to the timer that generated the message.

All you have to do is to check which timer triggered the message. That's all.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you can specify your own timer IDs. You don't Need to relay on the returned values of SetTimer, if you define the timer for a window. 
Care should be taken, if the window is a Standard window like a list view. Such Windows often have their own timer.

PS: I also think it is a bad coding style to use a timer without verifying if the timer id matches the one that I used when it was created.